# Handsontable data mapping with Excel sheet

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, handsontable

Is there any way to set up bridge between Excel sheet data and handsontable?

I want to display Excel sheet data to handsontable and also expect the same in reverse i.e. export handsontable data to Excel.

Anyone has a idea how I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

For Excel to handsontable, you can convert your excel data to json object, which can be put into handsontable as [data].

For the vice versa, I have already written a code in our project which exports handsontable data to excel. You can target the table formed in html as 'htCore'.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I would like to know that, if i stored data as JSON string; and want to use openXMLPowerTool for mapping the Excel data then is that logic works? I think openXMLpowerTool route based on the DOM object and not on the JSON string is it? Thanks again for 'htCore' suggestion, will look on it.